# if/ else statement to find if Iframe is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an embedded youtube video on my template where the source is being dynamically pulled in, and my client wants the ability to have either an image or the youtube video in that section at their discretion.

What I'm trying to do is have code that will find if the iframes src is empty, and if it is display an image instead. I feel like I'm fairly close but I need help getting it to work.

HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-8 product-video-section">
            <iframe id="ytplayer" width="560" height="315" src="youtubelink" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen wmode="Opaque"></iframe>
            <img class="videoImg" style="display: none;" src="imgLink" />
        </div>
```

JS

```
if ($('.product-video-section iframe').contents().find("body").length == 0) {
        //alert("This is the IF");
    }
    else {
        //alert("this is the ELSE");
        $('.product-video-section iframe#ytplayer').remove();
        $('.product-video-section .videoImg').css('display', 'block');
    }
```

Can someone help point out where I've gone wrong?

Comment: If the contents of the iframe is hosted on a third-party domain (which I'm assuming it is if you're showing a YT video) then you cannot access it through JS. You will be blocked by browser security.

Comment: ok, darn. Is there a way to check if the src is empty then?

Comment: <iframe id="ytplayer" width="560" height="315" src="" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test the iframe source attribute using [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```js
if (!$('iframe#empty').attr('src'))
{
    alert('empty');
}
    
if (!$('iframe#notempty').attr('src'))
{
   alert('empty too');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="empty" src="">
</iframe>

<iframe id="notempty" src="www.stackoverflow.com">
</iframe>
```

Note if there are more than one element that matches your selection you'll need to iterate each one